# Postgres row estimate is very low for hash join

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, execution-plan, postgresql-11

I have a query that keeps thinking that the result of a hash join will be 1 and I don't know which knob to turn to fix it.

The query takes a form field values in a revision of a document and maps them to the new revision of that document. Essentially it builds a map and then updates the id of the form field values to correspond with the new ids of the new document.

From studying the query plan, it appears the problem starts when the query planner estimates that the join between the `form_field_values` table and the `form_field_widgets` table should result in 1 row, when in realize it results in 1512 rows. That error seems to cascade through the query plan, causing it to iterate 300,000 times on an index at the top level.

I know the hash join is making a bad estimate, but I don't know how to fix it. I thought it might be an issue with the statistics on the `widget_id` field on `form_field_values`, and increased it from 100 to 1000 (and ran `analyze form_field_values`), but it didn't seem to do anything except make it choose a nested loop instead of a hash join when joining the `form_field_values` to the `form_field_widgets` (and still be slow).

If I reorganize the query as a CTE, it becomes much more performant, finishing in ~500ms vs ~40-60 seconds. The reason I don't want to use the CTE is that I feel like it's a hack, and that I should be able to tell Postgres how to plan the correct query.

My question is: how can I help Postgres understand that that hash join will not yield just 1 row?

Here's a link to [the query plan](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/SGt).

Here is the query:

```
select
    ffv.checklist_revision_id,
    target_ffw.id,
    ffv.updated_or_migrated_date
from form_field_values ffv
    join form_field_widgets source_ffw on (
        source_ffw.id = ffv.widget_id
    )
    join widget_headers source_wh on (
        source_ffw.header_id = source_wh.id
        and source_wh.deleted_by_id is null
    )
    join widget_headers target_wh on (
        target_wh.group_id = source_wh.group_id
        and target_wh.deleted_by_id is null
    )
    join form_field_widgets target_ffw on (
        target_ffw.header_id = target_wh.id
        and not target_ffw.deleted
    )
and ffv.checklist_revision_id = 'a738742e-9806-4e27-a409-fa64dc935987'
and source_ffw.template_revision_id = (
    select template_revision_id from checklist_revisions where id = 'a738742e-9806-4e27-a409-fa64dc935987'
)
and target_ffw.template_revision_id = (
    select template_revision_id from checklist_revisions where id = '9640ca39-3997-477d-baa9-f0b911052f5e'
);
```

Here's the plan:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Nested Loop  (cost=6497.49..13791.32 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=76.900..34072.298 rows=1512 loops=1)                                                                                                                                               |
|  Output: ffv.checklist_revision_id, target_ffw.id, ffv.updated_or_migrated_date                                                                                                                                                                      |
|  Buffers: shared hit=1815328 read=230999 written=18                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
|  I/O Timings: read=31242.307 write=0.280                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
|  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
|    ->  Index Scan using processes_pkey on public.checklist_revisions  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.424..0.424 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                                                    |
|          Output: checklist_revisions.template_revision_id                                                                                                                                                                                            |
|          Index Cond: (checklist_revisions.id = 'a738742e-9806-4e27-a409-fa64dc935987'::uuid)                                                                                                                                                         |
|          Buffers: shared hit=3 read=2                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
|          I/O Timings: read=0.408                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
|  InitPlan 2 (returns $1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
|    ->  Index Scan using processes_pkey on public.checklist_revisions checklist_revisions_1  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.677..0.678 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                              |
|          Output: checklist_revisions_1.template_revision_id                                                                                                                                                                                          |
|          Index Cond: (checklist_revisions_1.id = '9640ca39-3997-477d-baa9-f0b911052f5e'::uuid)                                                                                                                                                       |
|          Buffers: shared hit=3 read=2                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
|          I/O Timings: read=0.664                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
|  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=6479.76..13392.10 rows=50 width=40) (actual time=74.944..11916.589 rows=337928 loops=1)                                                                                                                                      |
|        Output: ffv.checklist_revision_id, ffv.updated_or_migrated_date, target_wh.id                                                                                                                                                                 |
|        Buffers: shared hit=322835 read=31876                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
|        I/O Timings: read=11369.829                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
|        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=6479.19..13220.30 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=74.438..880.954 rows=1512 loops=1)                                                                                                                                     |
|              Output: ffv.checklist_revision_id, ffv.updated_or_migrated_date, source_wh.group_id                                                                                                                                                     |
|              Inner Unique: true                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
|              Buffers: shared hit=6870 read=2405                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
|              I/O Timings: read=850.302                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
|              ->  Hash Join  (cost=6478.62..13211.72 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=73.705..97.682 rows=1512 loops=1)                                                                                                                                  |
|                    Output: ffv.checklist_revision_id, ffv.updated_or_migrated_date, source_ffw.header_id                                                                                                                                             |
|                    Inner Unique: true                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
|                    Hash Cond: (ffv.widget_id = source_ffw.id)                                                                                                                                                                                        |
|                    Buffers: shared hit=1449 read=263                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
|                    I/O Timings: read=86.606                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
|                    ->  Index Scan using form_field_values_checklist_revision_id_widget_id_idx on public.form_field_values ffv  (cost=0.57..6729.33 rows=1653 width=40) (actual time=1.145..20.193 rows=1512 loops=1)                                 |
|                          Output: ffv.id, ffv.created_date, ffv.created_by_id, ffv.updated_date, ffv.updated_by_id, ffv.organization_id, ffv.checklist_revision_id, ffv.widget_id, ffv.field_value, ffv.updated_or_migrated_date                      |
|                          Index Cond: (ffv.checklist_revision_id = 'a738742e-9806-4e27-a409-fa64dc935987'::uuid)                                                                                                                                      |
|                          Buffers: shared hit=1444 read=59                                                                                                                                                                                            |
|                          I/O Timings: read=16.992                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
|                    ->  Hash  (cost=6457.72..6457.72 rows=1627 width=32) (actual time=72.548..72.548 rows=3437 loops=1)                                                                                                                               |
|                          Output: source_ffw.id, source_ffw.header_id                                                                                                                                                                                 |
|                          Buckets: 4096 (originally 2048)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 247kB                                                                                                                                             |
|                          Buffers: shared hit=5 read=204                                                                                                                                                                                              |
|                          I/O Timings: read=69.614                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
|                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.form_field_widgets source_ffw  (cost=49.18..6457.72 rows=1627 width=32) (actual time=8.489..71.916 rows=3437 loops=1)                                                                        |
|                                Output: source_ffw.id, source_ffw.header_id                                                                                                                                                                           |
|                                Recheck Cond: (source_ffw.template_revision_id = $0)                                                                                                                                                                  |
|                                Heap Blocks: exact=183                                                                                                                                                                                                |
|                                Buffers: shared hit=5 read=204                                                                                                                                                                                        |
|                                I/O Timings: read=69.614                                                                                                                                                                                              |
|                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on form_field_widgets_template_revision_id_idx  (cost=0.00..48.77 rows=1627 width=0) (actual time=8.044..8.044 rows=3437 loops=1)                                                               |
|                                      Index Cond: (source_ffw.template_revision_id = $0)                                                                                                                                                              |
|                                      Buffers: shared hit=5 read=21                                                                                                                                                                                   |
|                                      I/O Timings: read=7.837                                                                                                                                                                                         |
|              ->  Index Scan using widget_headers_pkey on public.widget_headers source_wh  (cost=0.57..8.59 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.516..0.516 rows=1 loops=1512)                                                                             |
|                    Output: source_wh.id, source_wh.group_id                                                                                                                                                                                          |
|                    Index Cond: (source_wh.id = source_ffw.header_id)                                                                                                                                                                                 |
|                    Filter: (source_wh.deleted_by_id IS NULL)                                                                                                                                                                                         |
|                    Buffers: shared hit=5421 read=2142                                                                                                                                                                                                |
|                    I/O Timings: read=763.696                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
|        ->  Index Scan using widget_headers_group_id_idx on public.widget_headers target_wh  (cost=0.57..171.34 rows=46 width=32) (actual time=0.649..7.263 rows=223 loops=1512)                                                                      |
|              Output: target_wh.group_id, target_wh.id                                                                                                                                                                                                |
|              Index Cond: (target_wh.group_id = source_wh.group_id)                                                                                                                                                                                   |
|              Filter: (target_wh.deleted_by_id IS NULL)                                                                                                                                                                                               |
|              Buffers: shared hit=315965 read=29471                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
|              I/O Timings: read=10519.527                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
|  ->  Index Scan using form_field_widgets_2_header_id_idx on public.form_field_widgets target_ffw  (cost=0.57..7.63 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.065..0.065 rows=0 loops=337928)                                                                   |
|        Output: target_ffw.id, target_ffw.header_id, target_ffw.field_type, target_ffw.config, target_ffw.label, target_ffw.help_text, target_ffw.validation, target_ffw.key, target_ffw.template_revision_id, target_ffw.deleted, target_ffw.required|
|        Index Cond: (target_ffw.header_id = target_wh.id)                                                                                                                                                                                             |
|        Filter: ((NOT target_ffw.deleted) AND (target_ffw.template_revision_id = $1))                                                                                                                                                                 |
|        Rows Removed by Filter: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
|        Buffers: shared hit=1492493 read=199123 written=18                                                                                                                                                                                            |
|        I/O Timings: read=19872.478 write=0.280                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
|Planning Time: 0.893 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
|Execution Time: 34072.973 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here's the CTE version that performs well:

```
with map as (
    select
       source_ffw.id as source_widget_id,
       target_ffw.id as target_widget_id
    from form_field_widgets source_ffw
        join widget_headers source_wh on (
            source_ffw.header_id = source_wh.id
            and source_wh.deleted_by_id is null
        )
        join widget_headers target_wh on (
            target_wh.group_id = source_wh.group_id
            and target_wh.deleted_by_id is null
        )
        join form_field_widgets target_ffw on (
            target_ffw.header_id = target_wh.id
            and not target_ffw.deleted
        )
    and source_ffw.template_revision_id = (
        select template_revision_id from checklist_revisions where id = 'a738742e-9806-4e27-a409-fa64dc935987'
    )
    and target_ffw.template_revision_id = (
        select template_revision_id from checklist_revisions where id = '9640ca39-3997-477d-baa9-f0b911052f5e'
    )
)
select
    ffv.checklist_revision_id,
    m.target_widget_id,
    ffv.updated_or_migrated_date
from form_field_values ffv
    join map m on (
       m.source_widget_id = ffv.widget_id
    )
and ffv.checklist_revision_id = 'a738742e-9806-4e27-a409-fa64dc935987'
```

Here's the [query plan](https://gist.github.com/cdmckay/8e3e6c43a9aaf711554081575298a1c9) for the CTE. You can see that it still has bad estimates, but since the CTE is an optimization fence it doesn't affect the speed as much.

Comment: It is very hard to fix mis-estimates caused by correlations between columns in different tables. If you have a working workaround, go for it. From v12 on, you'll have to add `MATERIALIZED` to the CTE definition to have it behave as an optimization fence.